# Consider $\mathbb{R}^4$ with coordinate $(x,y,z,w)$ . Let $M$ be a $2$-manifold in $\mathbb{R}^4$ parametrized by

Tags: exterior-algebra

Consider $\mathbb{R}^4$ with coordinates $(x,y,z,w)$. Let $M$ be a $2$-manifold in $\mathbb{R}^4$  parametrized by $\gamma(u,v)= \begin{bmatrix}u^2-v^2 \\ uv \\ u+v \\ u-v \end{bmatrix}, \  \ u^2+v^2 \leq 1$. Let $\omega=dx \wedge dy+dz \wedge dw$ be a 2-form. $$ \text{Then 
 find } \int_M \omega.$$

I know that if $\omega=\sum a_{i_1, a_2,\ldots, a_k}(x) \, dx^{i_1} \wedge dx^{x_{i_2}} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{i_k} $ be a differential form and let $M$   be a $k$-manifold over which we wish to integrate, where $M$ has the parametrization $ M(u)=(x^1(u), x^2(u),\ldots, x^k(u))$ for $u$ in the parametrization domain $D$. Then the intgral is defind as $\int_M \omega = \int_D a_{i_1, i_2, i_3,\ldots, i_k}  (M(u))\cdot  J \ du^1 . du^2 \cdots du^k.$  where $J$ is the jacobian given by $J= \dfrac{\partial(x^{i_1} \cdots x^{i_k}) }{\partial(u^1\cdots u^k)}. $  **But how to apply this formula to the given problem. I really can't . Please help me**

Comment: Just use the fact that $dx =\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} du + \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} dv = 2u du -2vdv$. Then do the same for $dy$, $dz$ and $dw$. Finally use form-calculus to reduce to $f(u,v)du dv$.

Comment: I can get you, would you please do a little steps  and what is limit of integration .  Is it $ u^2+v^2 <1 $ ?

Answer (score 1):

So here are the details. Firstly we note that:
\begin{align*}
 dx &= 2u du -2vdv\\
 dy &= vdu + udv \\
 dz &= du + dv\\
 dw &= du -dv
\end{align*}

Then we have that:
\begin{align*}
 dx \wedge dy &= 2u^2 du \wedge dv - 2v^2 dv \wedge du\\
  & = (2u^2+2v^2) du \wedge dv\\
 dz \wedge dw &= -du \wedge dv + dv \wedge du  = -2 du \wedge dv.
\end{align*}

Now we have that:
\begin{align*}
 \int_M \omega = \int_{u^2+v^2 \leq 1} (2u^2+2v^2 -2)dudv.
\end{align*}

**Details:**
During my calculations I've used that $du \wedge du = dv \wedge dv =0$, $du \wedge dv = - dv \wedge du$ and multilinearity.

Comment: Please accept the answer if you find it satisfactory.

Comment: Yes sir the I found this answer very helpful. But tell me how to accept  formally , is there any option to vote up ? Actually I don't know how to accept a answer?

Comment: There should be a "check mark" at my answer (to the left - at the voting buttons).